# How to grep a test in Mocha with a specific name and under a specific parent?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Consider the following test cases:

```
describe("parent1", () => {
    it("mytest", () => {
        // ...
    });
});

describe("parent2", () => {
    it("mytest", () => {
        // ...
    });
});

describe("parent1", () => {
    it("myothertest", () => {
        // ...
    });
});

describe("parent2", () => {
    it("myothertest", () => {
        // ...
    });
});
```

I basically want to be able to run, via commandline, `mytest` under `parent1`.

#### Attempts

If I try the following:

```
mocha --grep 'mytest'
```

It will end up running:

- `parent1/mytest`
- `parent2/mytest`

Whereas if I try:

```
mocha --grep 'parent1'
```

It will end up running:

- `parent1/mytest`
- `parent1/myothertest`

How to achieve this?

Comment: What about `mocha --grep 'parent1/mytest'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox will it work? I can try

Comment: Does not seem to work, it cannot find any test to run

Answer (score 2):

It was actually quite simple since this is evaluated as a regex:

```
mocha --grep 'parent1 mytest'
```

Using a space is the solution it seems. I can successfully pinpoint tests like that.

#### Notes

It also works if test names have spaces in them:

```
describe("parent1", () => {
    it("my test", () => {
        console.log("AAA");
    });
});

describe("parent2", () => {
    it("my test", () => {
        console.log("BBB");
    });
});

describe("parent1", () => {
    it("my other test", () => {
        console.log("CCC");
    });
});

describe("parent2", () => {
    it("my other test", () => {
        console.log("DDD");
    });
});
```

Running:

```
mocha --grep 'parent1 my test'
```

Would work as expected.